# What regex trims arbitrary punctuation from the start and end of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input line that accepts a string of arbitrary length containing two entities: an identifier type from a small list, and an identifier that can contain letters, numbers, and punctuation. The two entities are separated by punctuation that might be, but is not limited to: `| : / \ ,`

I have some code that finds the identifier type in the supplied string:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < idTypes.length; i++){
 var search = rawInput.toUpperCase().search(idTypes[i]);
 if (search >= 0){
  var inputType = idTypes[i];
  var regEx = new RegExp(inputType, "i")
  var inputContents = rawInput.replace(regEx,"");
  console.log("This is type " + inputType + " with contents " + inputContents);
  return [inputType,inputContents];
 }
}
```

However, this does not capture the punctuation serving as separators:

if

`rawinput = "T14 11/15/11 | WPK |"`

then

`inputContents == "T14 11/15/11 |  |"`

whereas I would like

`inputContents == "T14 11/15/11"`

Is there a regex that will strip out all *leading or trailing* punctuation and white space, but will preserve the punctuation in the middle?

Comment: Your snippet does not work. Please make it a reproducible example.

Comment: Would you please show some input data and your actual regex?

Answer (score 0):

`(.+?)\s+[^a-zA-Z0-9]+.*$`

You can see its test at:
https://regex101.com/r/stDlXi/1

If you wish to specifically look for punctuation marks, then this will also do: `(.+?)\s+[\|\\/\?!\.,;:-]+.*$`. I have omitted brackets, guillemets, ellipsis, apostrophe, quotation marks etc. If you need to consider them you can include them inside the square brackets.